# Aren't Legendre's conjecture and Andrica's conjecture same?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

If Legendre's conjecture is true, couldn't we easily obtain $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_{n}}<1$ where $p_{n}$ is the $n$th prime?

$$p_{n+1}<(\lfloor \sqrt{p_{n}} \rfloor + 1)^{2}<( \sqrt{p_{n}}+ 1)^{2}$$
$$\sqrt{p_{n+1}}<1+\sqrt{p_{n}}$$
$$\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_{n}}<1$$

which is Andrica's conjecture.

Comment: The conjecture exists indeed. It's called [Andrica's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture)

Comment: Yes. And my question is arent Legendre's conjecture and Andrica's conjecture basicly same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Legendre's conjecture is [reported by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) to be that for each $n$ there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.  That would imply
$$
\lfloor \sqrt{p_{n+1}} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{p_n} \rfloor \le 1.
$$
For example, $\lfloor\sqrt{173}\rfloor=13$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{167}\rfloor = 12$.  Obviously in many cases the difference between integer parts of the square roots of consecutive primes is $0$.

Notice, however, that $\sqrt{1021}\approx31.953\ldots$ and $\sqrt{953}\approx30.87\ldots$.  Nothing in Legendre's conjecture says these cannot be consecutive primes, but Andrica's conjecture rules that out.

Comment: Wikipedia also said something about how "From 1640 to 1641 the might of colonial Portugal clashed with India's massive Maratha Empire in an undeclared war that would later be known as the Bicholim conflict." Or how Darth Sidious commissioned Michael Haydn's St. Francis Mass. Or that Seigenthaler had anything to do with JFK's death. Surely there's a better source for these math conjectures.

Comment: @DavidR. : The linked Wikipedia article cites this: $${}$$ Andrica, D. (1986). "Note on a conjecture in prime number theory". _Studia Univ. Babes–Bolyai Math._ 31 (4): 44–48. ISSN 0252-1938. Zbl 0623.10030  $${}$$

Comment: @DavidR. : BTW Wikipedia is explicitly intended to be a _tertiary_ source including citations of secondary sources (and also primary sources).  Wikipedia is not intended to be authoritative, but to enable you to find things that are authoritative.  (Secondary sources can do something that primary sources cannot: they establish "notability".  Riemann's original eight-page paper in which he states his famous hypothesis is a primary source, but it fails to establish notability, i.e. that mathematicians generally consider the topic noteworthy.) $\qquad$

Comment: And you are one of the few people who make Wikipedia's mathematical content worthwhile. If only editing of those articles was limited to you and a few others chosen by you!

Comment: @DavidR. : Thank you.  (I haven't actually chosen anyone besides myself.) $\qquad$